# How does one use Reinforcement Learning (RL) to solve a unconstrained optimization problem?

Tags: optimization, reinforcement-learning

I want to solve the a standard unconstrained optimization problem:

$$ \min_{x \in R^D} f(x) $$

and I want to solve it using RL (Reinforcement Learning).  One reason is that $f$ might be anything so it might be non-differentiable (so gradient descent tools are not obviously applicable). How does one go about doing this using RL? What would be the formulation as an MDP? What would be the policy and what would be the best algorithm to find the minimizer?

Comment: Why pose this as a RL problem? Plenty of traditional optimization methods are designed explicitly for this type of problem, such as partical swarm optimizers.

Comment: @CliffAB do you have a list that might solve my problem, in particular when $f$ is not differentiable?

Comment: I would point to the study of [derivative free optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative-free_optimization). The page on the link has a list of several approaches.

Comment: Note that there may be reasons you want to approach this as an RL problem. For example, most methods assumes that $f(x)$ can be evaluated exactly, but often in the RL framework, we can only evaluate a random variable that is conditioned on $x$. But so far in your question, I don't see why one wouldn't use a classic derivative free approach. Further details might show why.